# Sending 4k images over socket io causes javascript to freeze for a second

Tags: javascript, python, sockets, socket.io, electron

I am working on an Electron app that uses socket io to communicate images from a camera middleware program to the GUI. This is working but the issue is, every time a new image comes in the GUI freezes for about 2 seconds. The code I use within main.js in the electron app looks like this

```
socket.on("frame", data => {
        console.log("GOT FRAME");
        mainWindow.webContents.send("fodImage", data);
        if (cameraWindow) cameraWindow.webContents.send("fodImage", data);
    });
```

It appears the hangin happens when socketio detects the message though because if I comment out all the stuff within the function, the gui still hangs.

The python client code looks like this:

```
@sio.event
def getImage(cameraId):
    print(cameraId)
    print(f"Received GetFrame command for camera {cameraId}")

    frameBytes = None
    if cameraId % 4 == 0:
        with open("../data/fod1.PNG", "rb") as img:
            frameBytes = img.read()
    elif cameraId % 4 == 1:
        with open("../data/fod2.PNG", "rb") as img:
            frameBytes = img.read()
    elif cameraId % 4 == 2:
        with open("../data/fod3.PNG", "rb") as img:
            frameBytes = img.read()
    elif cameraId % 4 == 3:
        with open("../data/fod4.PNG", "rb") as img:
            frameBytes = img.read()

    # libcam = ctypes.CDLL('libcam.dll')
    # framesize = 4144*2822*3
    # framebytes = (ctypes.c_char * framesize)()
    # cameraID = 0
    # libcam.GetFrame(cameraID, framebytes, framesize)
    # framebytes = base64.b64encode(framebytes)

    sio.emit('frame', frameBytes)
```

Is there any way to stop this behavior? Or does it stem just from the fact that the images are very large? The images are about 16MB...

Comment: try using promise

Comment: How would you use promise for this? The actual hang up is happening when message is recieved,  not caused by the stuff within the data{} function

Comment: why are you using sockets to send images? Why not just use a simple get or post request?

Comment: mostly because the rest of the architecture is based on scoket io (theres a bunch of different messages getting passed around with socket io). Including the hook that is being used to initiate picture transfer.